# jQuery Selector ASP.NET GridView Column

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-selectors

how can i write a selector for specific column of GridView ?
i want to do something on mouseover of a GridView Column.
and i want to do it once.
Here is my gridview :

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ID="grvUsers" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Html Output :

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grvUsers" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="grvUsers_Label1_0">23</span>
            </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

GridView  DataBound

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("id")
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr(0) = "23"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        grvUsers.DataSource = dt
        grvUsers.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you post the generated html please?

Comment: Is it the `Delete` column or the other one?

Comment: This is delete, delete is just a sample name for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your itemtemplate, include a CssClass like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-CssClass="myRow">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you also need the header to be selectable, then include the HeaderStyle-CssClass property as well.

Then you can use `$("td.myRow").bind("mouseover", function() { });` to bind an event to each cell in the column.